# Pass variable defined on button click to another button click c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, directory, unique

I'm writing an ASP.NET application that on a Button click does these things

1. Create a unique directory in App_Data Folder using GUID
2. Copy an exe file and an excel template into the unique directory
3. Write an txt file from web page inputs
4. Run the exe file
5. The exe produces an output txt file
6. Put the output data into a asp table on the webpage
7. Write the output data from the txt file into the excel template

On second button click

1. Download unique excel file with data

Now all of the paths involved are variables. What I want to do is have a second button click which allows you to download the unique excel file filled with data. However whatever I try I cant use the unique path of the excel file in the second button click.

So how do I pass the variable defined in the first button click in the second button click. It is important the unique directories are created on the first button click.

Here is some of the code. There is quite a lot so I'm trying to only post the important stuff

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    UniqueDirectory d = new UniqueDirectory();
    string dirPath = Request.MapPath("~/App_Data/");             // point to the directory of wispp on the server
    string wisppExe = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/WisppNew.exe"); // point to the location of wispp on the server
    string fortranLib = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/libf60rts.dll"); // point to the location of the fortran libray file on the server
    string excelTemplate = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/WISPP_Template.xls");
    do

    {
        Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        string uniqueSubFolderName = guid.ToString();
        string uniquePath = dirPath + uniqueSubFolderName;

    }
    while (Directory.Exists(d.uniquePath));
    Directory.CreateDirectory(d.uniquePath);

    //copy files to new unique directory
    string wisppUnique = Path.Combine(d.uniquePath, "WisppNew.exe");
    string fortranUnique = Path.Combine(d.uniquePath, "libf60rts.dll");
    string wisppGraphUnique = Path.Combine(d.uniquePath, "WISPPGRA");
    string excelUnique = Path.Combine(d.uniquePath, "WISPP_Template.xls");
    string excelOutput = Path.Combine(d.uniquePath, "WISPP_Output.xls");
    File.Copy(wisppExe, wisppUnique, true);
    File.Copy(fortranLib, fortranUnique, true);
    File.Copy(excelTemplate, excelUnique, true);

    //write data into excel        
    FileStream outputFile = new FileStream(excelOutput, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
    xssfworkbook.Write(outputFile);
    outputFile.Close();
}

public void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //here I want to use variable excelOutput
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(excelOutput);

    if(file.Exists)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
        Response.ContentType = "Application/x-msexcel";
        Response.Flush();
        Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Hopefully this makes sense. I've tried putting the Response section of code in the first button click but this makes the data table not visible for some reason. Also I want the user to have the option to download the excel file so I ideally need a second button click.

Comment: easiest way is using a global variable that you set in btn1_click and get in btn2_click?

Comment: Use `Session["path"]`, first assign after first button is clicked, after second one is clicked just read the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not right because buttons can be clicked in any order but if you are going to go this route you can do something like this.

```
//hide second button
yourButton2.Visible = false;

public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    UniqueDirectory d = new UniqueDirectory();
    string dirPath = Request.MapPath("~/App_Data/");             // point to the directory of wispp on the server
    string wisppExe = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/WisppNew.exe"); // point to the location of wispp on the server
    string fortranLib = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/libf60rts.dll"); // point to the location of the fortran libray file on the server
    string excelTemplate = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/WISPP_Template.xls");
    do

    {
        Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        string uniqueSubFolderName = guid.ToString();
        string uniquePath = dirPath + uniqueSubFolderName;

    }
    while (Directory.Exists(d.uniquePath));
    Directory.CreateDirectory(d.uniquePath);

    //copy files to new unique directory
    string wisppUnique = Path.Combine(d.uniquePath, "WisppNew.exe");
    string fortranUnique = Path.Combine(d.uniquePath, "libf60rts.dll");
    string wisppGraphUnique = Path.Combine(d.uniquePath, "WISPPGRA");
    string excelUnique = Path.Combine(d.uniquePath, "WISPP_Template.xls");
    string excelOutput = Path.Combine(d.uniquePath, "WISPP_Output.xls");
    File.Copy(wisppExe, wisppUnique, true);
    File.Copy(fortranLib, fortranUnique, true);
    File.Copy(excelTemplate, excelUnique, true);

    //write data into excel        
    FileStream outputFile = new FileStream(excelOutput, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
    xssfworkbook.Write(outputFile);
    outputFile.Close();

    yourButton2.Visible = true;

    yourButton2.Click += (_sender, _e) =>
    {
        //excelOutput is still in scope
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(excelOutput);

        if(file.Exists)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
            Response.ContentType = "Application/x-msexcel";
            Response.Flush();
            Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
            Response.End();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Using this approach you will set up the button click event for the second button only after clicking the first. I would also suggest hiding the second button until the first is clicked.

Comment: thanks for the help. It almost works. Button 2 appears after the previous code is executed but when I click it the file doesn't download. The file downloads fine when I take it out of the Button2.click event.

Comment: I just ran a test and the second button worked fine. Can you update your question with what you have now? There may be something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @metal_man Session worked a treat. Nice and simple.

I added this after I defined my unique excel path.

```
    Session["excelPath"] = excelOutput;
```

And this is my button2 click

```
    string excelOutput = (string)Session["excelPath"];
```

Good article on Session State
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32545/Exploring-Session-in-ASP-Net